# Templates --> How to decipher, decide if necessary and create?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a few classes in a project that I inherited that are really old, last I knew they compiled with CodeWarrior 8. I am now in XCode 3.2

Here is an example of what I struggle with:

```
template <class registeredObject> 
typename std::vector<registeredObject>::iterator FxRegistry<registeredObject>::begin(void)
{
    return mRegistryList.begin();
}
```

The errors are:

```
no 'typename std::vector<registeredObject, std::allocator<_CharT> >::iterator FxRegistry<registeredObject>::begin()' member function declared in class 'FxRegistry<registeredObject>'

template definition of non-template 'typename std::vector<registeredObject, std::allocator<_CharT> >::iterator FxRegistry<registeredObject>::begin()'
```

How do I decide how to solve these and where do I start looking?

UPDATE: Here is the FxRegistry Class:

```
template <class registeredObject>
class FxRegistry
{
public:
    // Construction
    FxRegistry() {}
    ~FxRegistry();

    // List management
    void Register(const registeredObject &ob);
    void Unregister(registeredObject &ob);

    // List iteration
    typedef std::vector<registeredObject>::iterator iterator;
    typedef std::vector<registeredObject>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    std::vector<registeredObject>::iterator begin(void);
    std::vector<registeredObject>::const_iterator begin(void) const;
    std::vector<registeredObject>::iterator end(void);
        std::vector<registeredObject>::const_iterator end(void) const;

    FxSize size(void);
    void Insert(iterator iter,const registeredObject &ob);
    registeredObject &operator[](FxInt32 index) { return mRegistryList[index]; }
        void clear() {mRegistryList.clear();};
protected:
    vector<registeredObject> mRegistryList;
};
```

I get errors on every line above almost that are:
    error: type 'std::vector >' is not derived from type 'FxRegistry'
    error: expected ';' before 'iterator'

I thought an iterator was of vector type, so I would declare one vector iterator.

Comment: Well, the error message seems to be saying "*this member function here* was not declared in the class (you say it belongs to)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef std::vector<registeredObject>::iterator iterator;
typedef std::vector<registeredObject>::const_iterator const_iterator;
std::vector<registeredObject>::iterator begin(void);
std::vector<registeredObject>::const_iterator begin(void) const;
std::vector<registeredObject>::iterator end(void);
    std::vector<registeredObject>::const_iterator end(void) const;
```

In all those places you should be using:

```
typename std::vector<registeredObject>::iterator
```

`iterator` and `const_iterator` are dependent names (their meaning depends on what a particular instantiation of `vector<X>` might turn out to contain), and the language requires that you tell whether it is a type name or not, so the compiler can know without instantiating `vector<X>`.

Also it might make sense to use the typedefs you define.

As to what to start from - the first error on the list. :)

Comment: @UncleBens - I should figure out when to use  typedef and typename I dont know off the cuff.

Comment: Understanding it is good, but simple rule of thumb is to add `typename` whenever the compiler complains about something with templates.

Comment: @Kristopher, simple but bad rule :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- Is there an `#include <vector>` before the inclusion of that header?
- In the `protected` part of the class declaration, `vector` is not qualified with `std::`.
- Add `typename` before each of the `std::vector<registeredObject>::iterator` and ...`const_iterator` uses

Comment: @Kristopher - I updated the post with the class where this is defined. This is all in a single source file called FxRegistry.h